# Regarding error in servlet on execution

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have developed the below application with servlets but upon entering the username and password I am not getting the second page..Please advise...

first servlet is..

```
package Demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class SendRedirectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
            response)throws ServletException, IOException {
          response.setContentType("text/html");
          PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
          String name = request.getParameter("username");
          String password = request.getParameter("password");
          if(name.equals("james")&& password.equals("abc")){
          response.sendRedirect("Demo/ValidUserServlet");
          }
          else{
          pw.println("u r not a valid user");
          }
          }
}
```

The second servlet is ..

```
package Demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class ValidUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
              response)throws ServletException, IOException {
              PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
              pw.println("Welcome to roseindia.net " + " ");
              pw.println("how are you");
            }

}
```

and the login.html file is...

```
<html>

<head>
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="SendRedirectServlet">
  <p>Enter your name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="text" name="username" size="20"/></p>
  <p>Enter your password&nbsp; <input type="text" name="password"
   size="20"/></p>
  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"/></p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

and finally the web.xml is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Zulfiqar</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Demo.SendRedirectServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Zulfiqar</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SendRedirectServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Demo.ValidUserServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ValidUserServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I get the first page (http://localhost:9050/SendRedirect/Login.html) to enter the name and password but after clicking upon submit button I get the following error..

```
INFO: Marking servlet Zulfiqar as unavailable
15 Jul, 2012 8:14:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Zulfiqar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Demo.SendRedirectServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15 Jul, 2012 8:20:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO: Servlet Zulfiqar is currently unavailable
```

done the suggested changes , but still getting this error...

```
INFO: Marking servlet Zulfiqar as unavailable
15 Jul, 2012 9:11:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Zulfiqar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Demo.SendRedirectServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15 Jul, 2012 10:06:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO: Servlet Zulfiqar is currently unavailable
```

Answer (score 0):

`response.sendRedirect("Demo/ValidUserServlet");`

should be changed to

`response.sendRedirect("/ValidUserServlet");`

only this url pattern will invoke the servlet, as mentioned in your web.xml file part:

```
<servlet>     
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>     
    <servlet-class>Demo.ValidUserServlet</servlet-class>   
</servlet>   
<servlet-mapping>     
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>     
    <url-pattern>/ValidUserServlet</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

But your error seems to come from the other servlet after pressing the Submit button right?
Check whether the servlet class exitsts in the Demo folder in `WEB-INF/classes` as mentioned by Hardik.

Do a clean and rebuild of your project if you are running it from Eclipse. That fixed class not found errors for me most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

First,using package name in capital / title case is not encouraged. Always use small letters to define package name.

Second, Changing

```
response.sendRedirect("Demo/ValidUserServlet");
```

To

```
response.sendRedirect("/ValidUserServlet");
```

should work as mentioned in your `web.xml`.

Tomcat has some hot-deployment issues because of which it sometimes fails to load the class which is actually present in the classpath.

So, Check whether your tomcat has loaded new servlet class or not. 
Compile and publish the web project again.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Demo.SendRedirectServlet
```

Check you directory structure.

Does `SendRedirectServlet` exists under `Demo` directory at `/WEB-INF/class/Demo/SendRedirectServlet`